# Xamarin: How to Extend a WebView?

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin.android, extend

I am trying to extend a WebView in Xamarin.Android but getting the following exception:

Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Webkit.WebView' to type 'BottomNavigationViewPager.Fragments.TheFragment1+ExtWebView'.

I am wondering if/how I can extend a WebView.

I've tried implementing the following code; something similar works fine for a WebViewClient extension, but not WebView :

```
public class TheFragment1 : Fragment
{
    // this would run fine ->> protected static WebView _wv;
    protected static ExtWebView _wv;
    protected static View _view;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        _view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TheFragmentLayout1, container, false);
                   //the exception happens next line, works fine with a non-extended WebView
        _wv = _view.FindViewById<ExtWebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);

    }

    public class ExtWebView : WebView
    {
        protected ExtWebView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasWindowFocus)
        {
            base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);

            this.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }

        public override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();

            this.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }

    }
 }
```

I've also tried changing WebView in my axml file to tag ExtWebView instead of WebView :

```
<com.bitchute.BottomNavigationViewPager.Fragments.TheFragment1.ExtWebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.intelliabb.BottomNavigationViewPager.Fragments.TheFragment1.ExtWebView

if I switch com.bitchute.BottomNavigationViewPager.Fragments.TheFragment1.ExtWebView back to WebView, I get this exception:

Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Webkit.WebView' to type 'BottomNavigationViewPager.Fragments.TheFragment1+ExtWebView'.

on the line where I'm getting the WebView via FindViewById<> method of View _view

any advice would be awesome

EDIT: btw if you want a more complete context of my opensource project you can check this link.  The code is in TheFragment1.cs.  I've removed a bunch of it because it would be obnoxious for people to sift through the whole .cs file for me.

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav/blob/master/Fragments/TheFragment1.cs

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav/blob/master/Resources/layout/TheFragmentLayout1.axml

NOTE: the code in those files does not reflect these changes, as it's a published app, and I don't commit trash.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do this, in case anyone is interested.  I searched for a while and found stuff that came close but never got it completely.  This answer is not the same as for java android.  Keep in mind this is C#/Xamarin.Android *not* Xamarin.Forms.  If this is considered a duplicate I apologize and you can delete the thread.

I created a .cs file then class directly in the solution named ExtWebView.cs (you can probably move it into a folder but for simplicity sake I put it directly into the solution next to MainActivity.cs):

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Webkit;
using System;

namespace f00ProjectNamespace
{
public class ExtWebView : WebView
{

    //from what I read you need all of the constructors..
    //so type ExtWebView : WebView then right click on ExtWebView and hit
    //"generate all" *after* adding "using Android.Webkit;"
    public ExtWebView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public ExtWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public ExtWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }

    public ExtWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, bool privateBrowsing) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, privateBrowsing)
    {
    }

    public ExtWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
    }

    protected ExtWebView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    //now we can override methods inside the WebView like this: =]
    public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasWindowFocus)
    {
        //this method is invoked when the app changes focus
        base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
    }
}
}
```

very important, inside your layout you will need to tag the ExtWebView with the namespace like this: f00ProjectNamespace.ExtWebView (where f00ProjectNamespace is obviously your namespace); some people were saying to use the package name, and that didn't work for me.

```
<f00ProjectNamespace.ExtWebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_1_material"
    android:layout_centerVertical="false"/>
```

and inside my Fragment I got the WebView like this:

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var _view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TheFragmentLayout1, container, false);

        var _wv = (ExtWebView)_view.FindViewById<ExtWebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
    }
```

Works perfectly, no inflater errors now and I've got an extended WebView.  Hope it helps, works in the current version of Xamarin.Android as of 06/29/19